# Display information in related field when

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, subform, subforms

I have `two sub-forms` on a main form in access 2010. I want it to be that when I select a record in one of the sub-form, the other sub-form shows a related field.

For example, when `A record (date)` is selected in one sub-form, `The notes (a memo field)` should display in the accompanying sub-form.

What it is that I have a table that users make notes in one field is for the date and another is for the notes. I want to `create a sub-form that displays only the notes (form B)` when the date is selected in a sub-form (Form C) on the same form (FormA).

I need it this was as the main form allows for users to search for some values whic will populate Form C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnUpdate event, just reset (or refresh) the record source of the subform with the notes.  I'm assuming the notes subform has a recordsource that is a query?